# How to query search with multiple form inputs

Tags: laravel

I have a search functions that has multiple input fields and whenever one of the input is null, it is returning errors.

I have tried this code but it is just returning the query statement, and not the result itself

```
  $employees = DB::table('job_requests')
            ->select('job_requests.*','user_infos.*')
            ->leftJoin('user_infos','user_infos.user_id','=','job_requests.user_id')
            ->where('user_infos.role','=','0');

  if ($job_name) {
     $employees->where('job_requests.job_name','like',"%$job_name%");
  }
  if ($location) {
     $employees->where('job_requests.location','=',$location);
  }
  if ($gender) {
     $employees->where('user_infos.gender','=',$gender);
  }
  if ($salary) {
     $employees->where('job_requests.salary','<=',$salary);
  }
  if ($start_date && $end_date) {
     $employees->whereBetween('end_date',array($start_date,$end_date));
  }
  $employees->get();
```

I expect the output to be the result of the query

Comment: please show the whole code for the function

Comment: That is the whole code

Comment: is $job_name and the rest of the variables from a request ?

Comment: Can you show us what errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should Use This Code

```
$employees = DB::table('job_requests')
            ->select('job_requests.*','user_infos.*')
            ->leftJoin('user_infos','user_infos.user_id','=','job_requests.user_id')
            ->where('user_infos.role','=','0');

  if (isset($job_name) && !empty($job_name)) {
     $employees->andWhere('job_requests.job_name','like',"%$job_name%");
  }
  if (isset($location) && !empty($location)) {
     $employees->andWhere('job_requests.location','=',$location);
  }
  if (isset($gender) && !empty($gender)) {
     $employees->andWhere('user_infos.gender','=',$gender);
  }
  if (isset($salary) && !empty($salary)) {
     $employees->andWhere('job_requests.salary','<=',$salary);
  }
  if (isset($start_date) && !empty($start_date) && isset($end_date) && !empty($end_date)) {
     $employees->whereBetween('end_date',array($start_date,$end_date));
  }
  $employees->get();
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$employees = DB::table('job_requests')
            ->select('job_requests.*','user_infos.*')
            ->leftJoin('user_infos','user_infos.user_id','=','job_requests.user_id')
            ->where('user_infos.role','=','0');

  if (isset($job_name) && !empty($job_name)) {
    $employees = $employees->andWhere('job_requests.job_name','like',"%$job_name%");
  }
  if (isset($location) && !empty($location)) {
     $employees = $employees->andWhere('job_requests.location','=',$location);
  }
  if (isset($gender) && !empty($gender)) {
   $employees =  $employees->andWhere('user_infos.gender','=',$gender);
  }
  if (isset($salary) && !empty($salary)) {
    $employees = $employees->andWhere('job_requests.salary','<=',$salary);
  }
  if (isset($start_date) && !empty($start_date) && isset($end_date) && !empty($end_date)) {
    $employees = $employees->whereBetween('end_date',array($start_date,$end_date));
  }
  $employees->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify which table `end_date` field is in.